# how to setup previous/next message for inbox messaging

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a inbox messaging system and it works perfect. However I don't know how to implement a previous and next feature for the messages (so users can go to the next or previous message while viewing one). These are normal functions for viewing messages on the internet. Previous should mean previous by message creation time. Any help would be appreciated.

messages_controller:

```
  before_filter :set_user

  def index
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archieved"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
    if params[:mailbox] == "unread"
    @messages = @user.unread_messages
  end
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    if params[:reply_to]
      @reply_to = User.find_by_user_id(params[:reply_to])
      unless @reply_to.nil?
        @message.recipient_id = @reply_to.user_id
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.sender_id = @user.id
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
      redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def show
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     @message.readingmessage if @message.recipient == current_user
   end

   def destroy
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     @message.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted message."
     redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
   end

  def delete_multiple
      if params[:delete]
        params[:delete].each { |id|
          @message = Message.find(id)
          @message.mark_message_deleted(@message.id,@user.id) unless @message.nil?
        }
        flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
      end
      redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = current_user
    end
end
```

message model:

```
attr_accessible :subject, :body, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :read_at,:sender_deleted,:recipient_deleted
    validates_presence_of :subject, :message => "Please enter message title"

    belongs_to :sender,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
    belongs_to :recipient,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'

    # marks a message as deleted by either the sender or the recipient, which ever the user that was passed is.
    # When both sender and recipient marks it deleted, it is destroyed.
    def mark_message_deleted(id,user_id)
         self.sender_deleted = true if self.sender_id == user_id
         self.recipient_deleted = true if self.recipient_id == user_id
         (self.sender_deleted && self.recipient_deleted) ? self.destroy : self.save!
     end
    # Read message and if it is read by recipient then mark it is read
    def readingmessage
      self.read_at ||= Time.now
      save
    end

    # Based on if a message has been read by it's recipient returns true or false.
    def read?
        self.read_at.nil? ? false : true
    end

    def self.received_by(user)
       where(:recipient_id => user.id)
     end

     def self.not_recipient_deleted
       where("recipient_deleted = ?", false)
     end

     def self.sent_by(user)
        Message.where(:sender_id => user.id)
      end

    end
```

show.html (message view):

```
    <strong>From:</strong> 
    <%= @message.sender %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Received:</strong> 
    <%= @message.created_at.to_s(:long) %>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>To:</strong> 
    <%= @message.recipient %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Message</strong><br />
    <%=h @message.body %>
</p>
<p>
    <% if @message.recipient == @user %>

    <%= link_to "Reply", new_user_message_path(@user, :reply_to => @message.sender) %>

     |
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "Inbox", user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)%>
    |
    <%= link_to "Delete", [current_user, @message], :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this message?', :method => :delete %>

</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Message model:

```
def previous(same_recipient = true)
  collection = Message.where('id <> ? AND updated_at > ?', self.id, self.updated_at).order('updated_at ASC')
  collection.where(recipient_id: self.recipient_id) if same_recipient
  collection.first
end

def next(same_recipient = true)
  collection = Message.where('id <> ? AND updated_at < ?', self.id, self.updated_at).order('updated_at DESC')
  collection.where(recipient_id: self.recipient_id) if same_recipient
  collection.first
end
```

This is what we use in our Calendar system, very usefull to go Previous / Next with the Apppointments.

This rely on the `updated_at` column, which is kind of bad (if I update an old message it will confuse the next/previous). Maybe you want to use the `created_at` column, or your own.   With this you could do in your view:

```
# [...]
<p>
  <strong>Message</strong><br />
  <%=h @message.body %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Next', user_message_path(current_user, @message.next) %>
  <%= link_to 'Previous', user_message_path(current_user, @message.previous) %>
</p>
```

Comment: The model makes sense though I would have never been able to string that together without more experience. With calendars you would have to update it, though with messages there will be no option for user to  'update' or 'modify' their messages after it has been sent. I am getting a undefined method `show_user_message_path' on the view also.

Comment: What is your url helper to show a message? (You can run `rake routes` to list all your routes and helpers method)

Comment: so try with the url helper `user_message_path(current_user, @message.next)`

Comment: Thanks for the help you've been a big assistance!

Comment: What is your helper to show a message? I will update my answer with the correct url helper ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller for the viewing of the message, get 3 messages from the DB, and display the middle entry as the current message. Set the ID's to the previous and next message as variables.

Then in your view make two buttons: previous and next where their link urls are the path to the IDs you saved.